# Adding text to label expression in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, labeling, qgis-2.18, expression, dialog

Using QGIS 2.18

I have line feature and want to add a foot tick mark and a deg symbol to label
the label as of now  shows

"dis"   ||  "Azimuth"

339045

I would like it to show

3391' 45 deg

The expression is simple and i know the answer is simple as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this is what worked: "dis" || ' \'' || "Azimuth" || char(730) to produce a label of 1024 '208˚

Answer (score 3):

This may depend on the OS you are working on;

*Windows10*

```
 "dis"  || '\'' ||   "Azimuth"  || char(0176)
```

[image]

Comment: running Linux Elementary..  this is what i got...      1896'124~ so i t looks like all i need to do is add a space after the ' and figure out what char is the degree symbol.  Any further help would be great.  and Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user12577 sorry i am not sure, `char(b0)` perhaps?

Comment: It looks like this is what worked:  "dis"  || ' \'' ||   "Azimuth"  || char(730) to produce a label of 1024 '208˚

Comment: but after looking at I need the space to be between the ' and the "Azimuth"  now it is after the "dis" but before the '....

Comment: @user12577 please consider posting it as your answer for future readers on Linux.